# Preserving dtypes when extracting a row from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, dtype

Extracting a single **row** from a `pandas` `DataFrame` (e.g. using `.loc` or `.iloc`) yields a `pandas` `Series`. However, when dealing with heterogeneous data in the `DataFrame` (i.e. the `DataFrame`’s columns are not all the same dtype), this causes all the values from the different columns in the row to be coerced into a single dtype, because a `Series` can only have one dtype. Here is a simple example to show what I mean:

```
import numpy
import pandas

a = numpy.arange(5, dtype='i8')
b = numpy.arange(5, dtype='u8')**2
c = numpy.arange(5, dtype='f8')**3
df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
df.dtypes
# a      int64
# b     uint64
# c    float64
# dtype: object
df
#    a   b     c
# 0  0   0   0.0
# 1  1   1   1.0
# 2  2   4   8.0
# 3  3   9  27.0
# 4  4  16  64.0
df.loc[2]
# a    2.0
# b    4.0
# c    8.0
# Name: 2, dtype: float64
```

All values in `df.loc[2]` have been converted to `float64`.

Is there a good way to extract a row without incurring this type conversion? I could imagine e.g. returning a [`numpy` structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html), but I don’t see a hassle-free way of creating such an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach (but it feels slightly hacky):

Instead of using an integer with `loc` or `iloc`, you can use a slicer with length 1. This returns a DataFrame with length 1, so `iloc[0]` contains your data. e.g

```
In[1] : row2 = df[2:2+1]
In[2] : type(row)
Out[2]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
In[3] : row2.dtypes
Out[3]: 
a      int64
b     uint64
c    float64
In[4] : a2 = row2.a.iloc[0]
In[5] : type(a2)
Out[5]: numpy.int64
In[6] : c2 = row2.c.iloc[0]
In[7] : type(c2)
Out[7]: numpy.float64
```

---

To me this feels preferable to converting the data types twice (once during row extraction, and again afterwards), and clearer than referring to the original DataFrame multiple times with the same row specification (which could be computationally expensive).

I think it would be better if pandas had a DataFrameRow type for this siutation.

Comment: I tried this as well, but this means you have to pull out each value individually using `.iloc[0]`, i.e. you lose the ability to iterate over the row directly. But it seems like there is no better built-in way to do this. I guess I’ll just have to write my own function to build a corresponding structured array.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't help iterate over the row. My objective was to access various values from a single row with dot notation, so this was a bit clearer than `.iat`, even with the `.iloc[0]` muddying things.

Answer (score 2):

As you already realized, series doesn't allow mixing `dtypes`. However, it allows mixed data type if you specify its dtypes as `object`. So, you may convert dtypes of dataframe to `object`. Every column will be in dtype `object`, but every value still keeps it data type of `int` and `float`

```
df1 = df.astype('O')

Out[10]:
   a   b   c
0  0   0   0
1  1   1   1
2  2   4   8
3  3   9  27
4  4  16  64

In [12]: df1.loc[2].map(type)
Out[12]:
a      <class 'int'>
b      <class 'int'>
c    <class 'float'>
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

---

Otherwise, you need to convert dataframe to `np.recarray`

```
n_recs = df.to_records(index=False)

Out[22]:
rec.array([(0,  0,  0.), (1,  1,  1.), (2,  4,  8.), (3,  9, 27.),
           (4, 16, 64.)],
          dtype=[('a', '<i8'), ('b', '<u8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

Comment: Thanks, but both of these involve copying/modifying the entire `DataFrame`, right? That’s quite overkill just to get a single row.

Comment: yeah, it is the limitation of pandas when working on rows.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), use [[]] with .loc to return a DataFrame instead of a Series. This preserves the dtypes of the columns.
Using your original example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
>>> a = numpy.arange(5, dtype='i8')
>>> b = numpy.arange(5, dtype='u8')**2
>>> c = numpy.arange(5, dtype='f8')**3
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b, 'c': c})
>>> df.dtypes
a      int64
b     uint64
c    float64
dtype: object

>>> df
   a   b     c
0  0   0   0.0
1  1   1   1.0
2  2   4   8.0
3  3   9  27.0
4  4  16  64.0

>>> df.loc[[2]]
   a  b    c
2  2  4  8.0

>>> df.loc[[2]].dtypes
a      int64
b     uint64
c    float64
dtype: object

>>> df.loc[[2]].iloc[0].name 
2
```

Comment: This looks like it’s pretty much equivalent to [sandyscott’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62833506).